# What should I do for my rat with an injured eye?

Tags: health, injury, rat, eye-disease, first-aid

My rats got into a tiff last night or this morning and one has an eye injury. No vets near me treat rats and I don't know what to do. What should I do to help my rat?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Face/Eye injury on a male adult rat](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/21280/face-eye-injury-on-a-male-adult-rat)

Comment: I have moved him into a separate cage but I cant clean his wound as he tends to become aggressive when I get near him. I'm hoping it will resolve itself but his whole eye is swollen and bloody

Comment: Please ask about physiological saline solution in pharmacy and use it to flush the rat's eye. It won't do wonders, but at least it will clean the wound and hopefully ease the healing process.